# What kind of data structure is this? Python

Tags: python, flask

Studying Python, I am following an excellent Corey Schafer tutorial on Flask, he does this (I have extracted and summarized it for obvious reasons):

```
    from folder_app import app # I did it to follow the structure and that the code is equal to the original

    s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'], 1800) # key, seconds
    token = s.dumps({'user_id': 1}).decode('utf-8')
    s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])


    user_id = s.loads(token)['user_id'] # This is where I have the doubt

    print(user_id)
    print(type(s.loads(token)))
```

The code works, the problem I have is that although as you can see `(s.loads (token))` is a `dict`, I expected to see something like this `s.loads ({token ['user_id']})`, or `s.loads (token ['user_id'])` or something like that. That is, it is a `dict` but it does not seem so. And my doubt goes in the sense if this comes from a greater concept of those they call "pythonic" (which I have not seen so far), or is something that only happens particularly as in this case. Incidentally, `https://itsdangerous.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/jws/` this appears: `loads (self, s, salt = None, return_header = False)` the arguments are in parentheses. I hope it is clear what my doubt is :)

Comment: `user_id` is not an argument to `loads`. `s.loads(token)` is returning an object and that object has a field/key/attribute called `user_id`. That attribute is being retrieved with the `[user_id`] part

Comment: Thank you for commenting ... yes, that's how I assumed it, the point is that I can't find references in the help documents.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not answer per say but just to add to my comment. This is an example of how the `loads` function works on dictionaries with the json module. https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads. What it does is take a json string and return the dictionary type object in Python. Your Serializer is doing something similar. It takes the token string and represents it as an object like `dict`

The `s.dumps` I am assuming is similar to [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) which gives you the json string representation of python dictionary.

```py
import json
my_dict = json.loads('{"user_id": "Mane", "name": "Joe"}')
my_dict['user_id']
```

So you could just do `json.loads('{"user_id": "Mane", "name": "Joe"}')['user_id']` which is just chaining the operations.

Comment: Thx... here is the original code if you want to see it: ```https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/blob/master/Python/Flask_Blog/10-Password-Reset-Email/flaskblog/models.py```

Comment: It seems that the matter is based on something I had not seen so far, with trial and error I found it, I don't know if it is the answer, but it is the closest:  Ex. ```student = {'name': 'John', 'age': 23}  print(student['age'])
print((student)['age'])``` In both ways the ```dict``` returns the value, it does not have to be between the parentheses.

Comment: if you are referring to why the parentheses do not cause any problem in this case look at https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#parenthesized-forms. and on that same page look at https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists. But happy you figured it out

Comment: Yes, thanks you, that's what I mean, what happened is that when I had a doubt I didn't know it was a ```dict``` until much later, if not, I would have asked the simplest question.